# Datepicker is not functional but no error when inspecting the code?

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I have created a datepicker and was working fine, some strange reason it does not work now. But there are no error when inspecting. What could the reason for this? I know there was low shading and interrupted my development.

```
div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
 <div class = "col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-16">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
  <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>   
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"

    });
  });
```

// what i am using as a code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">



 <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
     </div>
  </div><br>
<br>
  <br/>
  <br/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/jquery.toggleswitch.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   // date functionality
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    autoclose:true

    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you check date-picker with `div` or `input`?

Comment: Where perhaps? i am using Jfiddle and dont seem to get any errors. Funny part this code was working, i dont remember modify it during the day. https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
     </div>
  </div><br>
<br>
  <br/>
  <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Testing with jQuery UI and unable to replicate the issue.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
  <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-16">
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I am not sure if you mean the [Bootstrap-Datepicker Plugin](https://formden.com/blog/date-picker) or [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: mine uses bootstrap Jquery UI. I did not able to get the results even if uses Jfiddle.net. What could an issue?